# Github-like Issue and Milestones Tracking in Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, git, cocoa, github

I'm a long time user of `Xode` with `git` Version Control on medium-sized `cocoa` projects and new to Github and I really fell in love with the Issue tracking system they propose.

I use things like `//FIXME:` or `//TODO:` when coding but they get buried so deep down in the code they can only be use locally. What I am looking for in a more macroscopic tracking of the issues, enhancements, milestones, etc I would like to define.

Are there any build-in functions or plugin do achieve the same thing with `Xcode` ? Or should I be looking at `git` possibilities ? Or are there just nothing available ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like GitHub and its issue tracker, but you don't want to pay for private repositories and/or you want to host them yourself, check out [GitLab](http://gitlab.org/). It's similar to GitHub, and has an issue tracker, but it's open source and you can deploy it on your own servers.

Comment: Follow-up comment after successfully deploying `gitlab` on my personal server : it was quiet a pain to get it to work, but well worth the trouble : Free `github` !